# Express.js and request: Headers unexpectedly reset themselves

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, request, request-headers

I'm using express with request to communicate with an API; a few controller files use exports so I can keep the route files pretty.

```
module.exports = function(app){

  var moment = require('moment'),
      request = require('request'),
      auth = require('../auth/auth.js')(app),
      apiUrl = process.env.API_URL;

  return {

    addProduct: function addProduct(req,res) ...
```

request.defaults are set in the auth file, login calls a function there to set headers to authenticate the user throughout the app.

```
auth.setToken = function(token, type, access) {
  auth.request = request.defaults({
    headers: {
      'x-access-token': token,
      'x-access-type': type,
      'x-access-level': access,
    }
  });
};
```

And then use request with some mods.

```
auth.request.get(apiPath, function(err, apiRes) {
  res.render(renderView, {
    items: items,
  });
});
```

Everything works great from the 'user' file, but I have a couple of other controller files I just added in, and for some reason the headers get reset (so my authentication gets lost) in every function in those files. I can literally copy and paste the 'user' file into the others and have the same problem, or I can put what I want in the other files back in the 'user' file and it works fine again. I can't figure out what I've done wrong but it's going to be very messy if I just have one file... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out- it was an issue of variables not getting passed around among controller files the way I assumed they were, so I created a new function to copy the token from session back into the headers and all is resolved.